# Linguistic glosses with Leipzig package including morpheme boundaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, leipzig

I just started using LaTeX and am using the Leipzig-package for linguistic glosses, that I also want to appear in a glossary. In the Leipzig package only the glosses themselves are defined, while morpheme-boundaries (- and =) are placed manually in the text.

This is how the shortcuts are defined: `\newleipzig{attr}{attr}{at\-tri\-bu\-ti\-ve} %attributive`

The first {attr} makes the shortcut, the second is what appears in the gloss and the glossary. If I add morpheme boundaries, e.g. `\newleipzig{attr}{=attr}{at\-tri\-bu\-ti\-ve} %attributive`, they of course also appear in the glossary.

Is there a way to define 2 separate outputs, i.e. one for glossed examples inluding the morpheme boundary and another one for the glossary?

Here is an example, in this case with the morpheme-boundaries outside the glosses:

```
\documentclass[11pt] {book}
\usepackage[a4paper, twoside, top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec} \usepackage{xltxtra} \usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist, mcolblock]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\let\eachwordone=\itshape
\let\eachwordtwo=\small
\def\gltoffset{-0ex}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\hfill {\small \sf #1}}
\newleipzig{attr}{attr}{at\-tri\-bu\-ti\-ve} %attributive
\newleipzig{an}{an}{adjectival noun} %adjectival noun
\newleipzig{act}{act}{ac\-tive} %active
\newleipzig{cv}{cv}{con\-verb} %converb
\newcommand{\Acv}{{\Act}{\Cv}}%
\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\leipzigtype,title=Abbreviations]
\begin{exe}
\ex \label{ex-bad-ghost}
\gll sulob ɖiʔke loʔ-gu=nu ɖuma bania=kaŋ\\
tree from fall-\Acv{}=\Attr{} spirit bad=\An{}\\
\glt `The spirit of someone who died from falling off a tree is a bad one.' \\
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly I would use `\newcommand` to define a macro that includes the affix/clitic connector and the abbreviation.

You don't really want to use `\newleipzig` to do this because `\newleipzig` defines a glossary entry, and the affix or clitic connector isn't properly the "short" form of the gloss. Also, like you noticed, the affix/clitic connector will show up in the glossary as well.

Here I have defined three new commands, which look just like the gloss macro but have a `b' prefix (b for bound?).

```
\newcommand{\bAttr}{={\Attr}}
\newcommand{\bAn}{={\An}}
\newcommand{\bAcv}{-{\Acv}}
```

Then you can use e.g. `\bAttr` in the interlinear glossed example instead of `\Attr`. I suppose if you ever decide that a morpheme you used to analyze as an affix is actually a clitic, it will make it easy to change the hyphen to an equals sign globally... but you would still need to go through and change the first lines of the examples by hand.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Exactly what I wanted. Now, I want to change the morpheme boundary I just have to change it in the \newcommand line instead of going through the entire text and still it turns up correctly in the glossary.

Thanks for the help :)